# Layer weight shape (1, 1) not compatible with provided weight shape (1,) for keras model

Tags: python, keras

I trained a model using Keras but forgot to save the model. This model was the part of a project where many other models were developed but now I can not proceed with the project. Fortunately I saved initial and final training weights. Now, I am trying to create a model with same final weights to get the predictions. I am compiling the keras model and using function model.set_weights to set the final training weights of lost model to new model.
Here is the code.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1,input_dim = 1, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['mse'])
listOfNumpyArrays = [np.array([0.2]),np.array([0.2])]
listOfNumpyArrays1 = listOfNumpyArrays
model.layers[0].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays)
model.layers[1].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays1)
```

Traceback

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-e63437554e30> in <module>()
----> 1 model.layers[0].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays)
      2 model.layers[1].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays1)
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1124                                  str(pv.shape) +
   1125                                  ' not compatible with '
-> 1126                                  'provided weight shape ' + str(w.shape))
   1127             weight_value_tuples.append((p, w))
   1128         K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
ValueError: Layer weight shape (1, 1) not compatible with provided weight shape (1,)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numpy array you created using `np.array([0.2])` has a shape `(1,)` whereas your weight array has a shape `(1,1)`. While they store the same amount data, numpy regards these as different shapes. You can fix this by doing the following:

Instead of:

```
listOfNumpyArrays = [np.array([0.2]),np.array([0.2])]
```

Use:

```
listOfNumpyArrays = [np.empty(shape = (1,1), dtype = np.float32), np.empty(shape = (1,1), dtype = np.float32)]
listOfNumpyArrays[0][0] = 0.2
listOfNumpyArrays[1][0] = 0.2
```

UNRELATED NOTE:

In this line:

```
listOfNumpyArrays1 = listOfNumpyArrays
```

It seems like you want to create two different lists of numpy arrays that are initialized to the same value. `listOfNumpyArrays1` will actually refer to the same list as `listOfNumpyArrays`, however. Therefore, when you do `set_weights` on `listOfNumpyArrays1`, it will modify `listOfNumpyArrays` as well. To initialize them to the same value while creating two different lists, you can use the following code:

```
listOfNumpyArrays1 = [np.copy(listOfNumpyArrays[0]), np.copy(listOfNumpyArrays[1])]
```

`np.copy` creates a new array that is a copy of the one you pass. This is can be written in a more pythonic way using list comprehension as follows:

```
listOfNumpyArrays1 = [np.copy(x) for x in listOfNumpyArrays]
```

Comment: hi @Swapnil Pande. Thanks for quick help. I implemented your suggestion. I am getting another error. It now says that layer weight shape (1,) is not compatible with provided weight shape (1,1) which is reverse of previous error. Please help me, Thanks in advance. ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-e63437554e30> in <module>()
---- 1 model.layers[0].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays)
      2 model.layers[1].set_weights(listOfNumpyArrays1)
ValueError: Layer weight shape (1,) not compatible with provided weight shape (1, 1)

Comment: You may be seeing this error because the bias weight matrix may actually be of size (1,). Try changing the second element in the list of numpy arrays to your original shape, np.array([0.2]).

Comment: thanks swapnil , this answer works for me. Thanks again for quick replies.